# Microsoft Word for Mac: ENTER-Key adds lines at the bottom

Tags: macos, microsoft-word

When I press the ENTER-key in Microsoft Word for Mac, the new line appears as far down as possible and if pressed again resizes all previous lines, and shifts them to be equally spaced apart.

Example video:
[image: Content Does not matter, only the behaviour]

Does somebody know, what might cause this? All preferences and settings are factory-new, or so I thought. Re-installing and googling did not help either.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely problem is that the Page Layout in the Normal.dotm template (the template that Word uses by default to create new blank documents) has the Vertical Page alignment set to ***Justified***.

If so, I do not know what may have caused your Normal.dotm to have ***Justified*** rather than the default, which is ***Top*** (although there may be a different default for CJK languages).

To find this setting for the open document, click the *Margins* icon at the left of the *Layout* tab, then select *Custom Margins...* at the bottom. In the dialog, select the *Layout* tab, and the **Page** *Vertical Alignment* dropdown is about halfway down the dialog. By default, it should be set to ***Top***.

To change Normal.dotm, you either have to copy it (just to be safe), delete it, then start Word and let it create a new empty one, or you have to edit it. Editing a document *based* on Normal.dotm is not enough.

I haven't checked this recently but to modify the normal.dotm what you probably need is to

- close Word
- Open a Finder Window and select your top level user folder (the one with your username)
- Select *View*->*Show View Options*, and check the **Show Library Folder** option. This will make the Library folder appear in the folder hierarchy under your user name when you try to open a document in Word.
- Open Word, then choose *File*>*Open...* and navigate to your user folder, then within that, to *Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/User Content/Templates*.
- Open *Normal.dotm*. Make the change to the Layout, then save Normal.dotm.

N.B. you cannot open Normal.dotm by double-clicking on it in the Finder - that just creates a regular .dotx based on Normal.dotm. But you can make a backup copy of Normal.dotm in the Finder, delete Normal.dotm, then open Word, which will then create a new Normal.dotm. But it sounds as if there may be a problem where Word will just recreate the existing problem, so it may be better to modify the existing Normal.dotm.